# unresolved dependencies of bz* files for rpm make from source

Tags: compiling, rpm, make

I am trying to do a build of rpm from source. I got through the `./configure` and ran through a good chunk of `make`. Unfortunately, I keeping getting stopped up on undefined references to `bzerror`, `bzwrite`, `bzflush` and others. Looking around online, I see these functions are part of the `bzip2` package. I've installed the development libraries, but I am still getting this message. Can anyone assist me in resolving these dependencies?

```
make[2]: Entering directory `/mnt/fedRoot/rpm-4.6.1/lib'
make  all-am
make[3]: Entering directory `/mnt/fedRoot/rpm-4.6.1/lib'
/bin/sh ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc -std=gnu99  -g -O2 -fPIC -DPIC -D_REENTRANT -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wmissing-prototypes -Wno-char-subscripts  -fno-strict-aliasing -fstack-protector   -o rpmdb_archive  ../db3/db_archive.o ../db3/util_sig.o librpm.la -lrt -lpthread 
gcc -std=gnu99 -g -O2 -fPIC -DPIC -D_REENTRANT -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wmissing-prototypes -Wno-char-subscripts -fno-strict-aliasing -fstack-protector -o .libs/rpmdb_archive ../db3/db_archive.o ../db3/util_sig.o  ./.libs/librpm.so /mnt/fedRoot/rpm-4.6.1/rpmio/.libs/librpmio.so -lmagic -lelf -llua -lm -lnss3 -lpopt -lrt -lpthread  -Wl,--rpath -Wl,/usr/local/lib

/mnt/fedRoot/rpm-4.6.1/rpmio/.libs/librpmio.so: undefined reference to `bzerror'
/mnt/fedRoot/rpm-4.6.1/rpmio/.libs/librpmio.so: undefined reference to `bzwrite'
/mnt/fedRoot/rpm-4.6.1/rpmio/.libs/librpmio.so: undefined reference to `bzflush'
/mnt/fedRoot/rpm-4.6.1/rpmio/.libs/librpmio.so: undefined reference to `bzdopen'
/mnt/fedRoot/rpm-4.6.1/rpmio/.libs/librpmio.so: undefined reference to `bzread'
/mnt/fedRoot/rpm-4.6.1/rpmio/.libs/librpmio.so: undefined reference to `bzclose'
/mnt/fedRoot/rpm-4.6.1/rpmio/.libs/librpmio.so: undefined reference to `bzopen'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [rpmdb_archive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/mnt/fedRoot/rpm-4.6.1/lib'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/mnt/fedRoot/rpm-4.6.1/lib'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/mnt/fedRoot/rpm-4.6.1'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The libraries would have to be picked up by `configure`. If you ran `configure`, then installed the bzip2 development files, then re-ran `configure`, it may still have picked wrong information from its cache. Run `make distclean`, then `./configure` again.

Comment: @Gilles... I definitely have not re-run configure. I will give this a go later today. Thank you for the information... I did notice that when I tried to re-run `make`, it seemed to pick from shortly before the area where I was getting the error. This tells me that there were some files created/compiled that it can keep track of. Do I need to get rid of those, or start over again from a fresh rpm folder when I re-run `./configure`?

Comment: @Hari: Under usual conventions, `make clean` removes everything written by `make`, but leaves stuff written by `configure`; `make distclean` removes everything created by either `make` or `configure`.

Comment: @Gilles ... Thanks for the info... off to the man pages for more :)

Comment: @Hari: This is a convention, it won't be in man pages. I think either the GNU make manual or the GNU coding standards describe these conventions (together with other less-widely followed conventions; `make clean` is pretty much universal, `make distclean` and its meaning with respect to `configure` is fairly common even outside GNU).

Comment: @Gilles: There is so much to take in with linux in general. I will add the GNU `make` manual to my pile of reading. Im determined to make this work...

Comment: `make distclean` worked as you explained... marking as answered.