# getting error "Can't create transaction lock" with rpm

Tags: rpm

I am slowly making progress on installing Fedora into a Logical Volume for a DomU using Package Management. I have (with the help of the wonderful people at [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)) resolved a number of issues, mainly surrounding `rpm` (see links below):

- [Unresolved Dependencies](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15067/unresolved-dependencies-of-bz-files-for-rpm-make-from-source)
- [Fedora root install](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15006/can-rpm-handle-an-install-of-another-os-into-another-logical-volume)
- [rpm issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14951/getting-cpio-bad-magic-when-trying-to-rpm-install-into-a-mounted-logical-volum)

I am using the `--root` option with `rpm` to change my newly built version of rpm to `/mnt/fedRoot`. I have also directed `rpm` to look at the `rpmrc` file in the build folder, rather than on the actual `/var/lib/rpm`. Now Unfortunately, on any rpm file I run though I am getting: `error: can't create transaction lock on /mnt/fedRoot (Is a directory)`. Looking online, I found a few pages that indicated this was an issue with the `__db.*`. Though deleting them and rebuilding the db within my `rpm` folder fixed another issue, I am still getting the `transaction lock` error.

Anyone have insight into this error?

Comment: If you have a file called /var/lock/rpm/transaction, try deleting it.

Comment: does the directory `/mnt/fedRoot/var/lib/rpm` exist ?

in analogy to http://www.redhat.com/archives/rpm-list/2007-May/msg00046.html , what does `rpm --root=/mnt/fedRoot -E '%{_rpmlock_path}'` say ?

Comment: Any updates on this problem? Answers to the two suggestions above?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of response, thanks for keeping me honest @Caleb. The command pointed to `/usr/lib/rpm/macros`. I think the issue was, I was trying to use a version of a fedora install rpm that wasnt compatible with the CentOS rpm I was using. I dont know if that actually makes sense (to linux experts), but I was able to install another version of CentOS without any issues, so that is what I am basing this on. I have decided to take a step back and try to learn a bit more about linux before I attempt a full-blown xen system again. For now I am using Fedora 14 as my main system.

Answer (score 14):

Try running your command as root. It worked for me.

Comment: Why does running as `root` work?

Comment: Yes why does it require root user access ?

Answer (score 0):

Something else is holding that lock. Wait a while. (It is usually the graphical package management tool refreshing it's view of what's available, or perhaps a run of yum).

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `/var/lib/rpm/.rpm.lock` file  (need to be root to do this).
That fixed it for me.

Comment: Now getting error `can't create transaction lock on /var/lib/rpm/.rpm.lock (No such file or directory)`

Answer (score 0):

check the file level permission for the root user, it has to be (read write and execute)

```
$ls -l /var/lib/rpm/.rpm.lock
-rwxr-xr-x
```

Answer (score 0):

2019 Update:::

Ran into a similar problem as asked ( RPM failed: error: can't create transaction lock on /var/lib/rpm/.rpm.lock (Resource temporarily unavailable) )

Solved by;

```
ps -ef|grep rpm
```

And killing 2 orphan rpm processes  as shown below ;

```
rpm --root / --dbpath /var/lib/rpm -i --percent --noglob --force --nodeps -- /var/cache/zypp/packages/download.o
/bin/sh /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.uHUmw1 7
```

I was then able to proceed with upgrading packages

Answer (score 0):

Got this issue as well today. I fixed with below command to make sure its folder is created.

```
mkdir -p /var/lib/rpm
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error, from trying the following under Scientific Linux release 6.10:

```
$ rpm -ivh ~/Downloads/kernel-rt-`uname -r`.rpm
error: can't create transaction lock on /var/lib/rpm/.rpm.lock (Permission denied)
```

My intent was to install the Kernel *source* package as a normal user to perform a build, and therefore spent a few hours trying to find why `rpm` needed to create the transaction lock when I wanted to install the *source* package under `~/rpmbuild`.

Eventually realised my error was `` kernel-rt-`uname -r`.rpm `` was expanding to the pre-built rpm for the running Kernel, and not the `src.rpm` file I actually wanted.

Actually specifying the name of the source rpm then worked to actually install the source package into `~/rpmbuild`:

```
$ rpm -ivh ~/Downloads/kernel-rt-3.10.33-rt32.33.el6rt.src.rpm 
   1:kernel-rt              warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: group mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
<<snip remove duplicate warnings>>
$ ls ~/rpmbuild/SOURCES/
extrakeys.pub
find-provides
genkey
kernel-rt-3.10.33-rt32.33.el6rt.tar.bz2
kernel-rt-3.10.33-x86_64-debug.config
kernel-rt-3.10.33-x86_64-rt.config
kernel-rt-3.10.33-x86_64-trace.config
kernel-rt-3.10.33-x86_64-vanilla.config
kernel-rt-3.10.33-x86_64-virt.config
linux-kernel-test.patch
merge.pl
perf
perf-archive
sanity_check.py
$ ls ~/rpmbuild/SPECS/
kernel-rt.spec
```

Answer (score -2):

As you are having error of 'can't create the transaction lock on rpm', to solve this error and get install the required package on your machine you just have to login to your root user through terminal window 'su -root' and then install your rpm package. The error gets solved.

Comment: Can you highlight what your answer adds above and beyond the existing answers?